# The other force in centrifuge

Tags: forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, centrifugal-force, fluid-statics

Consider a rotating centrifuge and a reference frame rotating with it. On every "piece" of fluid inside a centrifuge acts centrifugal force, but what are the other forces that make every piece stay in the appropriate place matching its mass?

Answer (score 1):

For a fluid element away from the wall, the other force is the pressure gradient in the fluid. For a fluid element in contact with the wall, the other force is the normal force from the wall.